# rails - request treated as HTML not json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

:( stuck here. Any help appreciated.

My log says

---

> Started POST "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-22 22:21:59 +0530
>   Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML

but i try requesting json through jquery

$.ajax({

```
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json",
url: 'http://localhost:3000/sign_in',
```

...

my controller

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 respond_to :json
def create

       respond_to do |format|
                format.html {
    .....
    }
        format.json {

    .....
        }
```

so what i am doing wrong here, i need to get the request as "#create as JSON"

Answer (score 2):

Add a `dataType` to your ajax:

```
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json",
url: 'http://localhost:3000/sign_in',
dataType: "json"
```

**EDIT**

You are posting some data to the action `create`, so you should just manipulate the data inside the action and then redirect it to somewhere else.... You should not render any info in the action create as it is a `post` and not a `get`. For example:

```
def create
  # find your user based on the params
  my_user = User.find(params[:id])
  # you can manipulate the user or even save it in a session

  # redirect to the action show for example
  redirect_to user_path(my_user)
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

In this way, if you access the url for the `show`action with a `.json` you will get the user info in json.

Comment: But dataType: "json" is for response. I have that eventually.

Comment: I believe your approach is not right. Please note my edited answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType: "json"` to your ajax request.